# split the string to get specific value on ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, split

I want to get two separate value from

```
/en/faq
```

the two separate value will be

```
lang =en
rem  =faq
```

I have used to split which was relatively much easier. Nonetheless, this is my approach which needs tweaking around, hopefully from your help I will be able to accomplish it.

```
string = "/en/faq"
lang   = string.split("/").first
rem    = string.split("/en/")

puts "/#{lang}/#{rem[1]}"
```

The desired output should be "/en/faq/" but the output is

```
"//faq"
```

i know i have got '.first' which is why I am getting a null value but could anyone help on getting the right results please?

thanks in advance.

Comment: try `lang   = string.split("/")` and `puts "/#{lang[1]}/#{rem[1]}"`

Comment: oh my god you are genius dude thats exactly what i have done just now, thanks :)

Comment: to implement that in application.html.erb. would i just put them inside <% ................. %> ?? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = "/en/faq"
lang   = string.split("/")
rem    = string.split("/#{lang[1]}/")

puts "/#{lang[1]}/#{rem[1]}"
```

**this does the trick and thanks to Sebi for his prompt answer!**